# What is wrong in this LEFT JOIN use?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have a litle doubt about the use of the **LEFT JOIN**.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    LD.id                                   AS disease_id,
    LD.disease_name_en                      AS disease_name_en,
    LDN.disease_name                        AS disease_name,
    LDN.description                         AS description,
    LD.image_link                           AS image_link
FROM LsDiseases                             AS LD
LEFT JOIN LsDiseaseName                    AS LDN
      ON LDN.disease_id = LD.id

WHERE 
     LD.id = 1 
AND
     LDN.language_id = 1
```

returning an output like this:

```
disease_id           disease_name_en          disease_name             description      image_link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    Newcastle disease        Newcastle disease        TEST             https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XXX
```

As you can see these fields:

- **disease_name_en**
- **disease_name**
- **description**

came from the **LsDiseaseName** that is a table containing translation for the record into the **LsDisease** table.

Ok it works. I used a **LEFT JOIN** because my idea was: "if exist a translation into the **LsDiseaseName** table (for a record of **LsDisease** table) these field will be valorized, if the translation doesn't exist return only the information into the **LsDisease** table and the previous field of the **LsDiseaseName** will be valorized with **null** value.

The problem is that changint this WHERE clause:

```
LDN.language_id = 3
```

using the id of a language for which I do not have translation

I am obtaining an empty resultset. So, what is wrong in my reasoning? What am I missing?

Comment: In order to get true left join behaviour, you should move `LDN.language_id = 3` to the `on` clause of the join.

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually first you are applying the join and then filtering the final result set for `id = 3` and thats the reason you are getting empty result set.

you should language filtering at the time of join itself.

```
SELECT
    LD.id                                   AS disease_id,
    LD.disease_name_en                      AS disease_name_en,
    LDN.disease_name                        AS disease_name,
    LDN.description                         AS description,
    LD.image_link                           AS image_link
FROM LsDiseases                             AS LD
LEFT JOIN LsDiseaseName                    AS LDN
      ON LDN.disease_id = LD.id AND LDN.Language_id = 3

WHERE 
     LD.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the LDN.Language_id = 3 in the WHERE clause changes the meaning of the left join to an inner join (because it does not allow for a null value)

Move that clause to the join statement

```
LEFT JOIN LsDiseaseName                    AS LDN
      ON LDN.disease_id = LD.id
      AND LDN.Language_id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this line into the Left join

```
LEFT JOIN LsDiseaseName                    AS LDN
      ON LDN.disease_id = LD.id
      AND LDN.language_id = 3
```